# Is pure water electrically conductive?

Tags: electricity, water

I know that water with some ions dissolved is a good conductor. I wonder whether it is true for pure water?

Comment: This sort of question shows a severe lack of effort on the part of the poster.

Comment: Indeed, since DI water is characterized by its resistivity. Although DI water is not pure either...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows [insufficient prior research](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/what-counts-as-sufficient-prior-research-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, pure water is not a good conductor at all, though the conductivity is not zero.

According to the LennTech webpage [Water Conductivity](http://www.lenntech.com/applications/ultrapure/conductivity/water-conductivity.htm):

> Pure water is not a good conductor of electricity. Ordinary distilled water in equilibrium with carbon dioxide of the air has a conductivity of about $10 \times 10^{-6}\ W^{-1}m^{-1} \ (20 dS/m)$.

The reason is that there are no abundance of ions in pure water to conduct the electricity.

A table of comparisons is provided from the [Physical Process Modelling](http://processmodeling.org/model_em/em_heat/indheat.html) website:

[image]

Note: the entry Water (distilled) is not the purest that water can be, see [Ultrapure water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrapure_water) which has significantly less conductivity than distilled water. But this table is given as a comparison with other materials.

Comment: Is it good or bad compared to other materials? What about water in isolation from CO2?

Comment: http://www.lenntech.com/applications/ultrapure/conductivity/water-conductivity.htm gives a few things to compare with. $CO_2$ would increase the conductivity quickly because in water it converts to carbonic acid, which contributes ions and thus conductivity.

Comment: @Anixx I have added a table with comparative information

Answer (score 4):

Even the purest water has *some, very limited* conductivity.

That's because water undergoes an auto-dissociation reaction:

$2H_2O(l) \rightarrow H_3O^+ (aq) + OH^- (aq)$.

The oxonium ($H_3O^+$) and hydroxide ($OH^-$) ions are charge carriers and allow limited current to be carried. But the total concentration of both ions together in ultra pure water is only about $2 \times 10^{-7}\:\mathrm{mol dm^{-3}}$, which is a very low value compared to ion concentrations in e.g. tap or river water.

Comment: What is this conductivity compared to other materials?

Comment: http://www.lenntech.com/applications/ultrapure/conductivity/water-conductivity.htm gives a few things to compare with. $CO_2$ would increase the conductivity quickly because in water it converts to carbonic acid, which contributes ions and thus conductivity.