# How to determine the radius of curvature of a convex lens?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, refraction, geometric-optics, lenses

Suppose there is an equi-convex lens made of glass which has a focal length ($f$) of 30cm. Then, can we not say that the radius of curvature, $R$ of the lens is twice the focal length, i.e. $R = 60cm$?

Why do we need to use the Lens Maker's Formula for the same, which in fact gives a different result :

$$
\frac{1}{f}= \frac{\mu_2 - \mu_1}{\mu_1}\left[\frac{1}{R_1}-\frac{1}{R_2}\right] 
$$

For $f=30 cm$, $\mu_1 = 1$, $\mu_2 = 1.5$, $R_1 = R$ and $R_2 = -R$, we get :

$$\frac{1}{30}= 0.5\times\frac{2}{R}$$
Or, $R=30cm$

How can one explain this? Also, how can the focal length be equal to the radius of curvature?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of [insufficient prior research effort](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/5779/84967). (OP: google *what is the relation between radius of curvature and focal lenght*, for example)

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform:  OP has found the formula, applied it correctly, and finds the result counterintuitive.  I think it is a fine question.

Comment: @RossMillikan that's why flags work by voting: if you desagree with me, its perfectly fine. Upvote the question. If I'm the only one who thinks that it should be closed, it won't. (I still think the question shows insufficient prior research; if OP had researched more, it wouldn't be that counterintuitive).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I did Google exactly what you've suggested before posting the question here. I did not get the answer as to **why** we cannot use the 2R method instead of the Lens Maker's Formula method.

Comment: @ag_dhruv what you actually did is irrelevant: all I can see is what you wrote in your post. Next time, try to make it clear you "*...[did] anything else you can think of that might get you the answer*" (see the link I posted before). If you did try everything else, it's a shame people thought you did not. Anyway, your question didn't get closed, so I was wrong. As simple as that. (Your question did get a few more close-votes in addition to mine, so some pleople thought the same as I did). Anyway, I'm glad you got the answer to your question.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Except insufficient prior research is a reason for downvoting, not for closure.

Comment: @ChrisWhite I'm fairly new to SE, and I'm sure you know what you're talking about. I assume you're right and I'm wrong. But the truth is, I commented that because I've seen people do that many times (not easy to find examples, because most of the times the question get closed, but you can see it [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/211825/is-pure-water-electrically-conductive)). Anyway, is it official that "insufficient prior research effort" should be downvoted instead of flagging for closing? Or is it just a matter of opinion?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Yes, I too have seen others use that reason. This may be revisited when we (eventually) revamp the homework close reason, but for now my opinion is that closure should be for objective violations of delineated policies. See also [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6001/closing-insufficient-effort-questions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intuitively, the radius of curvature has to depend on the index of refraction of the glass. If the index were $1$, the lens would have no effect at all.  If the index were very high, say $10$, it would not take much curvature to get a given f'ocal length.  Clearly we cannot just say the radius of curvature is twice the focal length.

You have applied the lens maker's formula correctly to your problem.  There is no problem with $R=f$, in fact that is always true for $\mu_2=1.5\mu_1$.  We are assuming a thin lens in this formula, so the diameter of the lens must be small compared with $R$.  If the focal length is $30$ cm and the diameter of the lens is $1$ cm the thickness is twice the height of a [circular segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment).  Given $R=30, c=1$ we have $h=R-\sqrt{R^2-(\frac c4)^2}=30-\sqrt{900-\frac 14}\approx 0.004$ so the lens is about $1$ mm thick

Comment: Is f=R/2 always true for a **mirror**, then?

Comment: Yes.  That is a purely geometric property of the surface.  As the light does not pass through the mirror, the focal length does not depend on the index of refraction.